# How to add data to multiple tables in .sdf?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have created a .sdf database in windows phone8 application, I want to use a single add function to add data to multiple tables. how to specify table name dynamically, so that i can insert to particular table.
I used this to insert to one table.

```
public void AddToDb(ElementTable data)
{
        var table = _DbdataContext.GetTable<ElementTable>();
        table.InsertOnSubmit(data);
        _DbdataContext.SubmitChanges();
       // GetCount();
}
```

Now, I want Make this function generic for ElementTable

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your own SQL query and execute it if you want to operate dynamic tables.

You can use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library), but it only supports writing raw `Where` and `Order` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that with LINQ to SQL on the Phone, as the LINQ to SQL api on Phone does not allow raw SQL